# how demanding is it to transition from iOS 6 to iOS 7 programming?

Tags: ios

I learnt how to program in iOS 6(mid-scale apps) in a university course last year. I was wondering, how much challenging is it to make a transition to iOS 7? I tried to check out for an iOS 7 full change-log but I only found info related to added features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not challenging at all. If you want to use some of the new API's then you will need to learn them. Creating a 'mid-level' app however has remained very much the same. 
The major differences are 'stock' element appearances but they are created the same way. Also views are now 'full screen' so that can be confusing at first if you aren't aware.